# Can Spring data Cassandra work with Dynamic model and Keyspaces

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I need to build an application that takes data from Kafka, persist data into some databases, and send the transformed data to another Kafka topic.

In my case, I need to parse the messages received from Kafka. The data will be coming from different devices and feed, so they will be having different schema. So I need to be able to create keyspace with message-metadata in runtime, and insert into that keyspace with schema received in runtime.

I don't know if Spring data Cassandra is capable of doing this. Like some sort of dynamic models instead of a fixed schema, so that I can use a map containing key-value pairs, instead of a fixed domain class.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you delimit the type of devices that are going to inject data into the topic? After all, you need to know the schema of the data before saving in Cassandra, especially to know which is the proper schema when reading Cassandra data, you have to define partition keys and other things that Cassandra needs to have a linear cardinality reading.

Comment: I was thinking about the following, if you have a registry with the different types of devices that can inject data, it implies that you can save in json format or in the one you want the scheme and then with that scheme think which is the best to read and write in Cassandra.

Comment: Although of course, if you really have so many different types (several tens, hundreds or thousands) of devices that are going to inject data into Cassandra with a different json scheme, then, yes, try to make the prototype and measure performance, to see what that is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what are you asking but you can define properties/fields of entities/tables that hold `Map<String, Object>` type so you could persist any data structure received from Kafka.

If that is something that would work for you let me know and I'll give a complete example how to set it up.

**Edit**

Best way to dynamically define keyspace would be to use `CassandraTemplate/ReactiveCassandraTemplate` queries with explicit keyspace:

```
@Autowired
private CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate;

public List<SomeClass> findByKeySpaceAndPartition(String keyspace, String id) {
  return cassandraTemplate.select(
      select()
          .from(keyspace, "table_name")
          .where(eq("id", id)),
           SomeClass.class);
}
```

For property conversion and mapping define an entity:

```
@Table("some_class")
public class SomeClass {

    @PrimaryKey
    private SomeClassPk pk;

    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT)
    private Map<String, Object> parameters;
}
```

Then define converters (one for writing and one for reading):

```
public class MapToStringConverter implements Converter<Map<String, Object>, String> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public String convert(@Nonnull Map<String, Object> source) {
        try {
            // do flattening here or whatever you need to do then return it stringified
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(source);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Error occurred while serializing map to JSON: {}", source, e);
        }
        return "";
    }

}

public class StringToMapConverter implements Converter<String, Map<String, Object>> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> convert(@Nonnull String json) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Problem while parsing JSON: {}", json, e);
        }
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

}
```

Then the only thing left is to wire in the converters in your Cassandra config:

```
@Override
public CustomConversions customConversions() {
    List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    converters.add(new StringToMapConverter(objectMapper));
    converters.add(new MapToStringConverter(objectMapper));
    return new CassandraCustomConversions(converters);
}
```

You should add this code in your configuration class which extends `AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration` or `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` depending on wether you are using synchronous or reactive `Cassandra` driver

Comment: So basically I need a table level multi-tenant application, and I have no knowledge of the how many tenant will be, and what the schema is like. For example, I receive a message from Kafka in a format of ```{tenantId: "device1", metadata1: d1, metadata2: d2, data: {names:["column1", column2], type::["system.string", "system.sring"], values:["value1", "value2"]}}```

Comment: Then I will create a table name called "tenandId" if not exist, and insert row with column1 and comun2.

Comment: @BuggyBug that should work but you should be aware of Cassandra limitations. It's almost imposible to query the table with conditions that are not partition key of the table, so no fancy complex where conditions. So for data analysis and BI you would need to pour data from Cassandra into some other base or use other technologies. It's mostly used to store large amounts of data with no loss of data (multiple nodes, masterless architecture, etc.).

Comment: I am aware that I need partition key and clustering key. It will be generated by using metadata, column1 and column2 are just payload under that compound key. My question is, is Spring data cassandra capable of doing things like define a model Class, like a class with {primary-key, clustering-key, Map<k,v>} attributes, and column1 and column2 will be in Map<k,v>, and the framework insert to {(partition-key, clustering-key),column1,column2,...}. Those columns are flat instead of in a Map object, since other applications(not implemented by me) will only consume flat data.

Comment: Also, the model class will be mapped to a keySpace dynamically, not in config file. Like I can pass tennantId when calling the persistent API, and the frame work will persist the object to the keyspace with tennantId, and flattening key-values in Map<k,v> together with primary-key, clustering-key generated from metadata. I was doing research and might probably write custom conversion method to flat the Map<k,v>, but I am not sure if its possible, and if it is possible to dynamically map to keySpace, which is received in runtime message not from static config.

Comment: So the conversion part is absolutely doable, but I'm not sure about dynamic keyspace persistence routing. I tried to create a Spring Data Cassandra app with reactive driver which uses multiple keyspaces for performance testing different data models few months ago and failed. I researched it and saw few tutorials how to do it but still wasn't successful, even dug deep into the Spring source code and still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Also there might be problems with performance if you'll have a large number of keyspaces, see: https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!searchin/java-driver-user/session/java-driver-user/p6edKPkFNBE/KnvcdcVg0bcJ   - solution in this thread is to use CQL queries with fully qualified names, but that would probably negate most of Spring Cassandra convenient features.